# Deploying Angular Application in Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins-pipeline, devops, cicd

I have created the build stage for an angular application in Jenkins which is successful. My requirement is I need to deploy it to a linux server which I have with me and the application should get started in a different port number without affecting the existing Port . Can anyone guide me on this to deploy the angular application using jenkins . Thanks

I tried to deploy in jenkins but I went through few articles relating it but in those it was mentioned using nginx to deploy the Angular application to a linux server .

Comment: Please show your workflow. It's impossible to give advice on concepts.

Answer (score -1):

**Here's a guide to deploying an Angular application using Jenkins:**

**Prerequisites:**

- **Jenkins Server:** Ensure you have a running Jenkins instance.
- **Node.js and npm:** Install Node.js and npm on the Jenkins server to build Angular projects.
- **AWS CLI (optional):** If deploying to AWS S3, install AWS CLI.
- **Git:** Install Git for source code management.

**Steps:**

1. **Create a Jenkins Job:**

   - In Jenkins, create a new job (e.g., "Angular Deployment").
   - Choose "Pipeline" or "Freestyle project" based on your preference.
2. **Configure Source Code Management:**

   - Point Jenkins to your Angular application's Git repository.
   - Provide credentials if required.
3. **Build Triggers:**

   - Set up triggers for automatic builds (e.g., Git push events, polling).
4. **Build Steps:**

   - Add build steps to perform the following:

     - **Install Dependencies:** `npm install`
     - **Build Angular App:** `ng build --prod`
     - **Copy Artifacts (optional):** Copy the `dist` folder to a deployment location.
     - **Deploy to Target Environment (optional):** Use plugins or scripts for deployment (e.g., AWS S3 plugin, AWS CLI commands).
5. **Save and Run:**

   - Save the job configuration.
   - Run the job manually or wait for triggers to initiate it.
6. **Monitor and Verify:**

   - Monitor the build logs for success or failure.
   - Access the deployed application to verify deployment.

**Example Pipeline Script (using Groovy syntax):**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/your-org/your-repo.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'ng build --prod'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                // Add deployment steps here, e.g., using AWS CLI or S3 plugin
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional Considerations:**

- **Node.js Version:** Ensure Jenkins uses the correct Node.js version for your project.
- **Unit Tests:** Integrate unit tests into the build process to ensure code quality.
- **Environment Variables:** Manage environment variables securely for different environments.
- **Security:** Implement security measures to protect deployment processes.